# How to use Apache to block a specific URL type?

Tags: regex, apache, url

I'm working on a Drupal site, and the client has requested to prevent any direct access other than the URL aliases defined.  That is,

- www.clientsite.com -> **Allowed**
- www.clientsite.com/some-internal-page -> **Allowed**
- someclientsite.com/node/add -> **Allowed**
- www.clientsite.com/node -> **Denied**
- www.clientsite.com/node/72 -> **Denied**

As you can see, I need to disable `/node`, `/node/` and `/node/[0-9]*` while allowing any `/node/some-link-text`

I've tried

```
<LocationMatch ^/node[\/]?([\d]*) >
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```

but it doesn't work for `/node/add`, though all other links work.  What regex do I need to fit these conditional matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/node/?$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^/node/[0-9]+$ - [F]
```

Comment: There is a time limit before answers could be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `RewriteRul` to send 403 as follows.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^node/?$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^node/[a-zA-Z/]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z/]*$ - [F]
```

This will work for,

www.clientsite.com/node/add -> **Allowed**

www.clientsite.com/node -> **Denied**

www.clientsite.com/node/72 -> **Denied**

As well as some extra features you might like,

www.clientsite.com/node/add/another/parameter -> **Allowed**

www.clientsite.com/node/add/another/72/param/ -> **Denied**

Comment: Read the question. `/node/some-link-text` needs to be allowed. This will block it.